# How to distribute type hints to PyPi?

Tags: python, setuptools, type-hinting

I've worked on adding Python 3.5 type hints to the responses library. But when I test making a distribution, `sdist` or `bdist_wheel`, it doesn't install my `.pyi` file. I can see it being part of the distribution, but it doesn't go further than that.

You can see what I got in my repo here: https://github.com/gaqzi/responses/tree/feature/type-hints-file

I read PEP484 which [mentions that stub files should be distributable.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#storing-and-distributing-stub-files) But I can't seem to figure out how. :)

Is there a problem because responses doesn't create a package? It's just a single module file and that's why it doesn't get added correctly?

What I see when I build the package:

```
% python setup.py sdist
running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to responses.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to responses.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing responses.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to responses.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'responses.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'responses.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
warning: check: missing meta-data: if 'author' supplied, 'author_email' must be supplied too
creating responses-0.6.0
creating responses-0.6.0/responses.egg-info
making hard links in responses-0.6.0...
hard linking README.rst -> responses-0.6.0
hard linking responses.py -> responses-0.6.0
hard linking responses.pyi -> responses-0.6.0
hard linking setup.cfg -> responses-0.6.0
hard linking setup.py -> responses-0.6.0
hard linking responses.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> responses-0.6.0/responses.egg-info
hard linking responses.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> responses-0.6.0/responses.egg-info
hard linking responses.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> responses-0.6.0/responses.egg-info
hard linking responses.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> responses-0.6.0/responses.egg-info
hard linking responses.egg-info/requires.txt -> responses-0.6.0/responses.egg-info
hard linking responses.egg-info/top_level.txt -> responses-0.6.0/responses.egg-info
copying setup.cfg -> responses-0.6.0
Writing responses-0.6.0/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'responses-0.6.0' (and everything under it)
```

After I've installed the package I got this:

```
% pip install dist/responses-0.6.0.tar.gz
[...snip...]
Installing collected packages: responses
Successfully installed responses-0.6.0
% pwd
/Users/ba/.virtualenvs/responses/lib/python3.5/site-packages
% ls responses*
responses.py

responses-0.6.0.dist-info:
DESCRIPTION.rst METADATA        RECORD          WHEEL           metadata.json   top_level.txt
```

Comment: Seems like including your ``.pyi`` file in ``MANIFEST.in`` works

Comment: Assuming that adding it to the `package_data` line with `include_package_data=True` is an acceptable substitute for `MANIFEST.in`, no, that doesn't work. See https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/ordered-set/pull/42, which has added both `ordered_set.pyi` and `py.typed`, but the types don't get packaged.

Answer (score 11):

According to [the mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installed_packages.html#making-pep-561-compatible-packages), you should pass `package_data={"my_package": ["py.typed", "foo.pyi"]}` as an argument to `setup` in `setup.py`. Note that `"foo.pyi"` is the relative path from the root of the package to be distributed to the 
stub file ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data)).

I've created an example repo where you can test this out at https://github.com/SKalt/stub_distrib_demo.

Comment: You can also glob all the .pyi files: `["py.typed", "*.pyi", "**/*.pyi"]`.

Comment: If you want to use `find_packages`: package_data={package: ["py.typed", "*.pyi", "**/*.pyi"] for package in setuptools.find_packages()}