# Protobuf response types in Pycharm not recognized

Tags: python, pycharm, protocol-buffers

When I am using the following, I can get the response, and it is valid. the response type is correct. In PyCharm, I want to be able to type "response." and hit "ctrl+enter" and see the "response.count" pop up as an option. The .pyi files were generated and seemining have the appropriate slots.

```
with grpc.insecure_channel(‘localhost:4443’) as channel:
     stub = SERVICESgrpc.CountServiceStub(channel)
     response = stub.GetCount(SERVICES.CountRequest())
     print(type(response))
     #the above line prints that the type is a CountResponse - how do I make my IDE recognize that
```

I have tried to give response a type with

```
    with grpc.insecure_channel(‘localhost:4443’) as channel:
         stub = SERVICESgrpc.CountServiceStub(channel)
         response = SERVICES.CountResponse()
         #response.count autocompletes here
         response = stub.GetCount(SERVICES.CountRequest())
         #prints that the type is a CountResponse - how do I make my IDE recognize that
         print(type(response))
         #works, but will not auto-complete response.count
         print(response.count)
```

Edit: Here is how the grpc prototype was compiled

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I../../../../googleapis -I../../protos --python_out=. --pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ../../protos/mypackage/serviceapis.proto
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing. It depends on how you're including the `.pyi` files into your project.

If you're directly including them, you'll need to mark the root directory of the generated code as a "Source Root" which will let PyCharm correctly index them.

If instead you've made that generated code into a package,  you'll need to ensure you've included the `*.pyi` files in that. See [How to distribute type hints to PyPi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571088/how-to-distribute-type-hints-to-pypi) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Python module grpc_tools.protoc uses a somewhat older version of protoc.

You should try using the binary protoc directly

reference : https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2638#issuecomment-1133604021